# Single line git command for saving all the changes in a working directory

Tags: git, version-control

```
git add .;git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only -z | xargs -0 git rm; git commit -m "Change"; git push;
```

I have compiled the command above. It adds the files in the directory. Then removes the files deleted from the "stage". Then it commits the changes and pushes them.

What are the implications of committing changes in this way?

I am new to git and learning to use it. The process of issuing multiple commands was too long and cumbersome.

**UPDATE: I am the only developer on this personal project at the moment. Testing & Debugging is done on a test server and that is where the updates are published directly through ftp. That is also setup as a private git directory on bitbucket. What I want is a version control/backup (project doesn't need specific user permissions to be preserved). In this scenario what are the implications?**

Comment: What do you mean by "removes the files deleted from the "stage""? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: The middle portion is finding out which files you deleted and trying to delete them again??

Comment: Using a generic commit message like this will make you curse yourself one day when you sit down and review your work.

Comment: the middle section is deleting files. It is not trying to find the files again and deleting them again. Those are commented in the git commit -c with a #

Answer (score 0):

Following are the implications of using commands this way:

1. You might not want to add all the changes all the time. This command will add absolutely every change which is not explicitly declared under `.gitignore`. Beats the whole purpose of have a staging area. Since you are starting with git, you must be working on a small set of files and adding all of them every time you are committing. On even a small(but real) project, you will frequently want to stage files selectively. `git add -p` gives you the power to even stage only parts of a certain file (p stands for patch).
2. The second part is unclear but it looks like you are finding out the files you deleted and trying to delete them again via xargs. Not needed. Deleted changes are committed as is and those deletions once committed will not spring up again.
3. The third part will be assigning same commit message on every single commit. Probably one of the worst things you could do as a dev is follow this generic commit message policy. When you sit back 3 months (or even 3 hours) later trying to find where did that bug come from, commit message will help you eliminate suspect commits at speed. Do you really think looking at diffs of every commit is easier compared to reading a commit message describing what changes the commit might contain? Also, have some mercy on the souls of other developers who might get your project :) .
4. The fourth part ensures you push every commit as it is made. Looks like svn where you need to communicate with central every time you are committing. Kinda defeats the localized and distributed nature of git. Plus it also ensures that you will almost never be able to do some cool stuff like rebasing.

These commands may be feeling like too much if you are committing just one or two files every couple of minutes. In reality though, you will wonder how you lived without them. Give it some time and follow the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes, two in one:

```
git add -A && git commit -m 'Your Message' && git push origin master
```

All you need to make it one is `&&`.